# Mavericks - terminal change default printer paper size

Tags: terminal, macos, printing

I've been using the following terminal command to set the current default printer paper size to a custom paper size

```
defaults write com.apple.print.PrintingPrefs DefaultPaperID -string 154x216
```

Unfortunately looking in preferences panel this is not setting the paper size, please does anyone know where this default paper is now set in Mavericks

Comment: just missed it from my code entered here, i'll edit thanks

Answer (score 2):

The setting in System Preferences changes the DefaultPaperID key in `~/Library/Preferences/org.cups.PrintingPrefs.plist`. Try to change that key instead:

```
defaults write org.cups.PrintingPrefs DefaultPaperID 154x216
```

Quit and reopen applications to apply the changes.

`defaults read com.apple.print.custompapers` shows the IDs of custom paper sizes.

Comment: Big Sur: defaults read com.apple.print.custompapers
2021-07-09 11:36:22.616 defaults[15155:6014592] 
Domain com.apple.print.custompapers does not exist