# Setting default paper size for specific printer with lpadmin

Tags: macos, command-line, printing

I am trying to set up two default paper sizes for two seperate "printers" (which both point to the same URL) - one is ARCHD and one is ARCHE.

Using lpoptions -p Printername -l shows me that both of those are options.

I've used various commands and tests such as

```
lpadmin -p 48x36 -v "popup://<URL>/Printer_36x48" -E -P "/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/HP DesignJet Studio-36.ppd" -o HPPrintQualityPreset=middle -o PageSize=ArchE -o Media=ARCHE -o MediaType=HPUniIDSatinPhto -o HPPaperSource=Roll
```

When I check the settings with

```
lpoptions -p 48x36 -l
```

It shows me that those settings all "took". It has the little star next to the ArchE under paper size.

However, when I go to actually print (from Adobe Acrobat, Illustrator, and preview) and print to that printer, it has the correct default paper type and paper source, but it defaults to letter size paper.

How can I made the lpoptions default paper size actually show up in practice?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/188758/489896

Answer (score 1):

The lpadmin default and the GUI default are two separate things. (And indeed, the printer's own on-board default is another.)

[Mavericks - terminal change default printer paper size](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107797/mavericks-terminal-change-default-printer-paper-size)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532622/set-default-paper-size-of-printer-via-mac-terminal-command

If you're using the print dialog in applications anyway, any reason that two Print Presets with the different page size and other settings for the same printer wouldn't be more useful?

Or just configure the default paper size of each printer queue in the GUI, assuming you're not going to change it constantly or programmatically.

Comment: From what I can see both those options change the default paper size for all printers, right? That doesn't work for us since we also have normal printers too which are the primarily used onces and are letter sized.
"The same url" was not quite true - they go to two seperate print queues which are treated differently by our print management software (Pharos).

When you say change the paper size of each print queue in the GUI, what do you mean? Do you mean the system settings printers and scanners?  I only see the option for changing the default paper size which applies to all printers.

Comment: I think you're best off setting the default as a Printer Preset in the GUI for each print queue. Any reason you need to use the command line?

Comment: By "the gui" do you mean the Systems Preferences -> Printers and Scanners -> the default page size at the bottom there? That applies to all the printers, not only one printer. I have both normal printers and also wide format printers and so need different settings on each.  (If you meant a different GUI, please let me know how to get to it). I do not need the command line; I just couldn't get the GUI to do it so I went in the terminal and that also didn't have the desired effect.

Comment: No: Printer Presets are collections of print menu options, saved in the print menu.